# Reference request: definiitions of exact C* algebra and group C* algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am writing my Ph.D. thesis and I would like to cite the specific papers where the concept of exact $C^*$ algebra and group $C^*$ algebra was defined.
In the book of Brown and Ozawa "$C^*$-algebras and finite-dimensional approximations", they mention a paper of 1999 for the definition of exact group but I found previous papers with at least the concept of exactness in the group $C^*$ algebra, for example

> de la Harpe, Pierre; Robertson, A. Guyan; Valette, Alain. On exactness
> of group $C^*$-algebras. Quart. J. Math. Oxford Ser. (2) 45 (1994),
> no. 180, 499--513. MR1315460.

I wonder if someone clarifies to me these references. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The concept of exactness and the major results on it, say up to mid 1990s, are solely due to Eberhard Kirchberg. Although he has obtained them much earlier, he wasn't able to publish them because he was a political prisoner of East Germany and because he doesn't write. In any case, what is studied in the cited paper is about exactness of full group C*-algebras. It's different from (although related to) exactness for groups.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I found the reference 'POSITIVE MAPS AND C*-NUCLEAR ALGEBRAS' of Kirchberg as the first one who is cited by referring to the definition. However, I cannot read this paper. Do you know if this is the first paper that mentions the definition? Do you know a survey o book with the history of Kirchberg? I would like to add it to my thesis. Thank you very much

Comment: The paper "Positive maps..." is a short report for the conference in Leipzig in 1977. Kirchberg introduced the notion of exactness for $C^*$-algebras and started to explore it. He was interested at that time exactness of the full group $C^*$-algebra (of a locally compact group, as he already knew $C^*(F_2)$ was not exact). In that paper, Kirchberg noted the news that Choi had found embedding of $C_r^*(Z/2 * Z/3)$ into the Cuntz algebra (and hence $C_r^*(Z/2 * Z/3)$ is exact but not nuclear). Probably, this is the time he started to think about the reduced group $C^*$-algebras.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification!